# pass a jQuery variable on load to mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Hello all: i have a question regarding a jQuery function and a php variable

I have 3 dropdowns that depends on each other to populate themselves from a mysql TABLE. 
When the window is loaded the Project dropdown has 3 options: 1 2 3, "Type" just A, B(default is A) and "User" dropdown has nothing. So when user selects project 1, type A the third dropwdown populates by a dropdown and a external php document:

This is the jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Performs an action when Project dropdown value is changed
    $("#projectSelector_id").change(function () {
        $("#user_id").load("getCust.php?project_id=" + $("#projectSelector_id").val() + "&type=" + $("#Type_id").val());
    });
});
```

when project has changed, the user id loads according to the getCust.php
here the getCust.php contains this variables:

```
$project= $_GET['project']
$type = $_GET['type']
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROW = $type ";
$result = ($query);
while......
{
}
```

this only works when a project is selected, thats when the _GET variables are filled. In this case if i echo this query the varibale $type is empty cause there is no project selected.
 My question is how can i have the default option for the "type dropdown" in the jquery calling this php document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the default value of your dropdown

```
var defaultOption = $('#Type option[selected="true"]');
```

where `Type` is the id of dropdown.

Comment: thanks, i have edited my question.. Would this get the default value if i want to echo the variable _GET['type']

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the default will be a valid value, rather than something like "Select product". If this is so, then you can just run the function immediately and it will pick up the values currently on the page.

You can do this with `trigger('change')` or the shorthand form `change()`:

```
$("#projectSelector_id").change(function () {
    $("#user_id").load("getCust.php?project_id=" + this.value + "&type=" + $("#Type_id").val());
}).change(); // <-- call the function immediately
```

NB that, for added performance, I have changed `$("#projectSelector_id").val()` to `this.value`. Note also that, while you send `product_id=`, your PHP looks at `$_GET['product']`. Presumably they want to be harmonised.